# MYSQL update if exists or insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get the following SQL to work however it seems to skip the insert function. Essentially updating should take priority as most of the time it should fire.

```
UPDATE `teams-tasks`
        SET status=(:s), name=(:n), description=(:d), importance=(:i), applies=(:a) 
        WHERE teamId =(:t) AND date=(:da) AND playerId =(:p) AND creatorId =(:c);
        IF (SELECT ROW_COUNT() = 0);                    
        INSERT INTO `teams-tasks`
            ( status, date, creatorId, teamId, playerId, name, description, importance, applies ) 
        VALUES 
            ( (:s), (:da), (:c), (:t), (:p), (:n), (:d), (:i), (:a) ))
```

what am i doing wrong?
i am using php pdo for my database connection if it matters

thanks

Comment: ive also tried   IF @@ROWCOUNT == 0 without any luck

Answer (score 0):

User replace into query which makes sure if the row exists it will update the data, if row does not exists it will insert the date.

to check the duplicate entry it compares the primary key internally

e.g.

```
REPLACE INTO table_name(column_name1,column_name2,…)
VALUES(value1,value2,…)
```

e.g.

```
REPLACE INTO offices(officecode,city)
VALUES(8,'San Jose')
```

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

You should use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

For example

```
INSERT INTO AggregatedData (datenum,Timestamp)
VALUES ("734152.979166667","2010-01-14 23:30:00.000")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  Timestamp=VALUES(Timestamp)
```

Comment: How does it determine that there is a duplicate key as each entry i am either inserting or updating has a unique id. However, the entry could be the exact same for more than one row. That is what i am using the teamId, date and playerId in the where is to ensure that it is the unque row for that player on that team on that date. How would i accomplish my desired resultÉ

Comment: INSERT INTO `teams-tasks`
    ( status, date, creatorId, teamId, playerId, name, description, importance, applies ) 
   VALUES 
    ( (:s), (:da), (:c), (:t), (:p), (:n), (:d), (:i), (:a) ))   
   ON DUPLICAT KEY UPDATE
    status=(:s), name=(:n), description=(:d), importance=(:i), applies=(:a) 
   WHERE teamId =(:t) AND date=(:da) AND playerId =(:p) AND creatorId =(:c)

Comment: And i understand the that where cannot be implemented like i have in the above statement

Comment: In my above examples, would my new expression become:                           INSERT INTO `teams-tasks`
    ( status, date, creatorId, teamId, playerId, name, description, importance, applies ) 
   VALUES 
    ( (:s), (:da), (:c), (:t), (:p), (:n), (:d), (:i), (:a) ))   
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    IF( teamId =(:t) AND date=(:da) AND playerId =(:p) AND creatorId =(:c) )
    THEN status=(:s), name=(:n), description=(:d), importance=(:i), applies=(:a)